# Why do people say "truth will out"?

Tags: grammar, figures-of-speech

When speaking of (alleged) attempts to lie or cover up the truth, someone might say "truth will out," an expression that seems to make no sense: where is the verb?

"Will" can be used as a verb, but it only works in connection with another verb, as in "He wills it to happen."  "Out" can also be used as a verb, but it's a transitive verb: "Bob outed Alice as a spy."  Neither of these conditions apply in this phrase.

If the word "come" was added in there, we would have "truth will come out," which is both grammatically correct and appears to clearly convey the meaning of the phrase.  But it gets used without any verb, which makes the meaning of the phrase a lot less clear.

What exactly does "truth will out" mean, and why is the expression used in such an ungrammatical way?

Comment: I don’t actually know for sure (never thought about it before), but it seems likely and intuitively correct to me to suppose that this is a remnant of a feature that is common to most Germanic languages, but is no longer there in English: that demotic modals can carry a sense of movement in and of themselves, taking as their argument a simple adverb of location or direction. Compare now old-fashioned expressions like “I must away” in English; in other Germanic languages you can also say “I must home”, “I will in”, etc. _Want_ still partly works like this (“I want out”), too.

Comment: Though the verb is not used intransitively in this sense in many other expressions, [AHD, Collins and RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/out) are in agreement that 'truth will out' uses the main verb 'out': << **out**  v.intr.
To be disclosed or revealed; come out: _Truth will out._ >> (AHD).

Comment: Because they heard someone else say it.

Comment: There is in fact a long tradition of sayings (apophthegms) cast without any verb at all.  It seems to make them striking and memorable.  So the famous idea that the body is the tomb of the soul was expressed with the two nouns ‘soma sema’ (σώμα σήμα).  Or the early atomist,Democritus wrote:  “The cosmos a stage set.  Life a stage entry.” (ο κόσμος σκηνή. ο βίος πάροδος).  He goes on: “you came on, you saw, you went off again.”.  Sound vaguely familiar?  But you don’t need a verb to understand just what he meant.  So the saying ‘Nothing too much’ (μηδέν αγαν) needs no verb.

Comment: @Tuffy It’s not uncommon for the basic copula of a language (i.e., _be_ in English, _εἰμί_ in Ancient Greek) to be omissible in many perfectly normal situations. English happens not to be one of those languages, but Ancient Greek is, so the fact that some Greek apophthegms have no copula isn’t really an argument for English phrases lacking a verb (especially not a non-copular verb). Besides, ‘truth will out’ _does_ have a verb (or possibly even two).

Comment: @Edwin Conversely, the OED has it under the adverb/preposition/interjection entry, as [sense 5, “With main verb implied”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133395#eid33098549). And even AHD, Collins, and Webster don’t have _away_ or _hence_ as a verb to fit parallel constructions like “let us away” or “let us hence” (both archaic, true, but still found as more or less fixed phrases).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I take your point.  Mind you,  I take it the ‘missing’ word is not the copula.  It is not even certain whether it is any specific verb: ‘come’? (possibly); ‘get’? (maybe); ‘leak’? (would work)...  It does not have to be ‘be’.

Comment: @Tuffy Yes, in “truth will out” it’s certainly not a copula. My point was that the Greek apophthegms (at least the ones you quoted and what I’m familiar with) are a specific type of construction where specifically a copula is elided, and “truth will out” is a different construction and a different kettle of fish. While the apophthegms may seem superficially similar, I don’t think there is any actual relation between the two phenomena.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Point well taken.  Although ‘nothing in excess’ may be an exception.

Comment: @Janus [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/out) has: << **out** (v.)

Old English utian "expel, put out" (see out (adv.)); used in many senses over the years. ... sense of "disclose to public view, reveal, make known" has been present since mid-14c. >> (Though it isn't clear about the detailed history of the intransitive sense.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Absolutely—no doubt about the existence of the verb and its meaning. I just don’t think AHD/Webster/Collins are right to associate the word in ‘truth will out’ with that verb; I think it’s the adverb, though admittedly I can’t think of any possible way of making sure one way or the other.

Answer (score 10):

It is idiomatic, a the similar expression “murder will out” is from Chaucer (14th c.).
The sense appears to be from “out” used as a verb here meaning:

***[Out](https://www.etymonline.com/word/out):***

> sense of "***disclose to public view, reveal, make known***" has been present since mid-14c.

(Etymonline)

***[Truth will out](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/390200.html):***

> is from Shakespeare's The Merchant of Venice, 1596:
>
> LAUNCELOT: Nay, indeed, if you had your eyes, you might fail of
> the knowing me: it is a wise father that knows his
> own child. Well, old man, I will tell you news of
> your son: give me your blessing: truth will come
> to light; murder cannot be hid long; a man's son
> may, ***but at the length truth will out.***

(Phrase Finder)

> The phrase "truth will out", or "truth will become public", appears as early as William Shakespeare's works, in particular, the Merchant of Venice. ***It may have been an entirely new concept of Shakespeare's, as he sees the need to explain its meaning as analogous to [murder will out](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/murder_will_out).***

(Wiktionary)

From ***Chaucer, "Nun's Priest's Tale," c.1386***:

> ***Mordre wol out*** that se we day by day.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Just to add that "will" could either mean "wants" - hence "wants [to be] public" or, more likely, it is in the sense of expressing the habitual nature of something, as in "Boys will be boys" or "Dogs will chase cats."

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "truth will out" basically means that no matter what one does to cover something up, the truth WILL get out. It is used in such an ungrammatical way because it was quoted from writing by Shakespeare.

Comment: The answer to the question why is it used in such an ungrammatical way is that it is a phrase quoted from a play by Shakespeare written in blank verse. As such it was never required to follow any particular rules of grammar, and Shakespeare made up his own rules (and his own words, for that matter).

Comment: @AytAyt I am very sorry if I confused you or anyone. I thought that taken together all the responses to the original question had  answered it, except for what seemed to me to be the obvious point that normal rules of grammar do not apply to verse - and still less to verse written centuries ago. But for that to be obvious, it has to be realised that the phrase in question is a quotation.  Please respond by further comment on what more there is that I could say. I should be very happy to say more.